# onfocus stop work after reload content in parent object

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dhtml

I load content to the  using AJAX.
in content you can find this line of code:

```
<input onfocus='searchItems("sContainer", this)' onblur='searchItemsStop()'/>
```

first time when I load the content `onfocus` and `onblur` events works. But when I reload the content `onfocus` and `onblur` stop working.

in firebug I noticed that for every reload of content `onfocus` and `onblur` events start to duplicating.

[image]

how can i solve this?

EDIT:

the loaded content is a table with list of products. I load this into popup div on user button click.

the searchItems check the input for user query, and show in the list only products which match to the query.

When user close popup, all content is removed by `.removeChild`, so why the events are not deleted with the content too?

Comment: When you reload what content exactly? What does `searchItems` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in different place that i watched.

`searchItems` function was using referance only to the first (deleted later) input element.

Problem solved.